# How to solve "Cannot create an instance of class CoursesViewModel" error on Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I am new at Kotlin and I am trying to create a ViewModel instance using dependency injection (dagger.hilt). I am getting "Cannot create an instance of class CoursesViewModel" error and I don't know why. Could you help me with this?

CoursesViewModel.kt

```
class CoursesViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
        private val courseDao: CourseDao
) : ViewModel() {
}
```

AppModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCourseDatabase(
            app: Application,
            callback: CourseDatabase.Callback
    ) = Room.databaseBuilder(app, CourseDatabase::class.java, "course_database")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .addCallback(callback)
            .build()

    @Provides
    fun provideCourseDao(db: CourseDatabase) = db.courseDao()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplicationScope() = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
}
```

CourseDatabase.kt

```
@Database(entities = [Course::class], version = 1)
abstract class CourseDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    // DbSet equivalent
    abstract fun courseDao(): CourseDao

    // Inner callback class
    class Callback @Inject constructor(
            private val dbProvider: Provider<CourseDatabase>,
            @ApplicationScope
            private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope
    ) : RoomDatabase.Callback(){
        override fun onCreate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase){
            super.onCreate(database)

            val courseDao = dbProvider.get().courseDao()

            applicationScope.launch {
                courseDao.insert(Course("my course")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CoursesAllFragment.kt

```
class CoursesAllFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel : CoursesViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_courses_all, container, false)

        // Set the recycler view
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.lectures_classes_recycler_view)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(context))
        recyclerView.setAdapter(CoursesAllAdapter(viewModel)) // Line 26. see: logcat
        return view
    }
}
```

logcat output:

```
2021-04-05 23:52:33.202 17137-17137/com.something.something E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.something.something, PID: 17137
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.something.something.Courses.CoursesViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
        at com.something.something.Courses.Fragments.CoursesAllFragment.getViewModel(Unknown Source:2)
        //In the following line, "CoursesAllFragment.kt:26" is blue, which is where I pass the view model to an RecyclerViewAdapter.
        at com.something.something.Courses.Fragments.CoursesAllFragment.onCreateView(CoursesAllFragment.kt:26)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2950)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:277)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2177)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2088)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1959)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:306)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:249)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:792)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:583)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:682)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:159)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:290)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:119)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1578)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1690)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:792)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:583)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:355)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solveVerticalMatchConstraint(Direct.java:636)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:407)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solvingPass(Direct.java:178)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:642)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:159)
2021-04-05 23:52:33.202 17137-17137/com.something.something E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:290)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:119)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1578)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1690)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:792)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:583)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:355)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solveVerticalMatchConstraint(Direct.java:636)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:455)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:387)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solvingPass(Direct.java:178)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:642)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:159)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:290)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:119)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1578)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1690)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1156)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:792)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:583)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:355)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solveVerticalMatchConstraint(Direct.java:636)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:407)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:446)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solvingPass(Direct.java:178)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:642)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:159)
```

Stackoverflow doesn't let me paste the rest of the logcat output due to having too much code in the question body.

Comment: `CoursesAllFragment` is missing `@AndroidEntryPoint`, but you should also update your Hilt to the latest version anyway, You're on around 2.28-alpha or so, and the current is 2.33-beta.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce your suggestion solved it. Add this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark your fragments and the activities containing them with the `@AndroidEntryPoint` to let Hilt know to inject there.

Also the latest version of Hilt has deprecated the `@ViewModelInject` annotation in favour of annotating the actual view model class with `@HiltViewModel` and using the standard Dagger `@Inject` annotation on the constructor.